# Выравнивание li

Tags: css

[image]

Есть вот такой список, в котором один элемент съезжает вниз и занимает целую строку (из-за того что текст 3 элемента слишком большой. Как можно это исправить? Magento, у элементов есть классы first и last.

Comment: Если есть возможность подключить jquery, то можно сделать все на много лучше с помощью http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

Задайте ссылке

```
display: block; 
height: (N*2)px;
overflow: hidden
```

, где N - интерлиньяж текста (line-height), тогда текст будет обрезаться до двух строк

Answer (score 0):

задайте блоку

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

флоаты обязательно уберите. ну и марджины допишите какие нужно. и да прибудут с вами печеньки

Comment: Тогда они будут выводиться неровно по верхней линии. Думаю автору надо все же табличный вид.

Comment: @SnowLeo, зато верстка будет гибкой и блоки будут тянуться вне зависимости от количества контента